# Referencing a Cell in DAX Formula Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, dax

I have imported a large data set into the data model in Excel and am working on a pivot table from it. I want to create a measure that can reference a cell in the worksheet.

Currently I have

```
=SUM(Column 1) * 83 (from cell A3)
```

I don't want to hard code it; I want the flexibility to update the 83.

How can I do that?

Comment: If I'm not wrong what you are trying is not possible,, but there is one possibility, put 83 in cell and just NAME it and use that name as  Parameter then it will works,,, [You may check this also](https://www.daxpatterns.com/parameter-table/) ,,, Please [Check this also](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/09/15/referencing-individual-cell-values-from-tables-in-power-query/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with named ranges or cells?

Go to A3. In the top lefthand corner is a dropdown box that says "A3". Click inside it and name cell A3 whatever you want e.g. scalefactor

Now in any other formula write:

```
=SUM(column1)  * scalefactor
```

You can also define names using Formulas ribbon > Define Name or edit it in Name Manager.